# How to update field with specific criteria

Tags: process-builder

I need to update specific fields no of channels>250 or more and state contains with specific set of strings to update different fields

So, I take criteria like

> Billing_State_Province__c Equals Formula

```
IF( CASE( UPPER([Opportunity].Billing_State_Province__c ), 'CA', 1,
'NV', 1,'BC', 1,'OR', 1, 'WA',
1,'ID',1,'MT',1,'UT',1,'WY',1,'CO',1,'AK',1,'HI',1,'AZ',1,'NM',1,'BRITISH
COLUMBIA',1,'ALBERTA',1,0) >=1, true, null )
```

But it throws an error saying expected text something.

How to make criteria like above

My Process is like But not accepting condition.

[image: Process]

Comment: The formula you have provided would only work if you are trying to specify the value for a checkbox field.

Comment: So,how i can do because sometimes my users add state like cA or Ca and i don't want to setup any validation rule on it.Any other way to do this

Comment: How about lay out what you are trying to accomplish? It sounds like you are just updating the wrong field (`Billing_State_Province__c` instead of `More_Than_250_Channels__c`).

Comment: @AdrianLarson channels>250 is other criteria.so i have two conditions to one channels > 250 and Billing_State_Province__c equal state above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I change my formula condition in process builder criteria.Like below in if condition i am return State field value if it is true.then i am update fields.

My Criteria

[image: Process]